# Display jumbotron background emoji

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

now i have [jumbatron like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbxGt.jpg)

and i want to add random emoji (three at all) on right side of this. I made it in paint
[how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBVly.jpg)

How can i do that?

My css:

```css
.jumbotron {
 position: relative;
 background-color: #563d7c;
 color: #fff;
 padding-top: 100px;
 margin: 0px;
 word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<header class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
 <div class="container">
  <h1 class="display-3"><?php echo $data['CFG']['s_name']; ?></h1>
  <p class="lead"><?php echo $data['CFG']['s_about'] ?></p>
  <p><a class="btn btn-success btn-lg" href="index.php?mode=start" role="button"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> <?php echo $this->lng['load_client']; ?></a></p>
 </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
.myimg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 180px;
    right: 50px;
    top: 100px;
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ecLz8hsw/)